# Post query trigger not firing after LOV population in oracle forms 10g

Tags: forms, oracle, triggers, oracle10g, lov

I have a master detail form in which details in a second block are displayed based on the first block.  The problem is, when i use a LOV selected value the post query trigger is not firing in the second block and i cannot understand why.  The relationship is set up correctly as records are correctly displayed when i navigate through them using the default keys on the form.  My code to open the LOV is as follows:

```
DECLARE
    SUCCESS BOOLEAN;
    BEGIN
    do_key('clear_form');
    SUCCESS := SHOW_LOV('STUDENT_LIST');
    set_item_property('registration.netid', property_true);
    END;
```

Comment: The `post-query` trigger has nothing to do with LOVs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call execute_query to make post_query fired.

Comment: I realised that after, now i have the issue of when i change my value via the LOV i have a "do you want to save changes?" message.  From forum searching i think this has something to do with the item status being changed due to selection of a new item but i don't know how to bypass this message i have tried execute_query(no_validate) and a clear_block(no_validate) but to no avail.  I have all non database items set to NO and insert allowed/query allowed on all my item properties in order to allow them to receive the LOV values.  I am really stuck.

Comment: this is not related with your original question, any way you called:

do_key('clear_form');

so do you have a Key-CLRFRM trigger in your form? 

if there is no key-clrfrm, change calling do_key('clear_form') to be
clear_form('no_validate');
or call clear_form('no_validate'); in trigger Key-CLRFRM .

Comment: This still does not work but thankyou anyway, i suppose i will have to keep searching for a similiar problem in forums to fix this issue.